# Content-Length can't be trusted when reading a response from SslStream?

Tags: c#, https, .net-core, tcpclient, sslstream

Playing with TcpClient and NetworkStream on .NET Core 2.2.
Trying to get the content from https://www.google.com/

Before I continue, I'd like to make clear that I do NOT want to use WebClient, HttpWebRequest or HttpClient classes. There are a lot of questions where people had encountered some problems using TcpClient and where responders or commenters have suggested the use of something else for this task, so please don't.

Let's say we have an instance of SslStream obtained from TcpClient's NetworkStream and properly authenticated.

Let's say that also have one `StreamWriter` that we use to write HTTP messages to this stream and one `StreamReader` that we use to read HTTP message headers from the response:

```
var tcpClient = new TcpClient("google.com", 443);
var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
var sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false);
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("google.com");
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(sslStream);
var streamReader = new StreamReader(sslStream);
```

Say we send a request in the same way as a Firefox browser would have sent one:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: sr,sr-RS;q=0.8,sr-CS;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Which causes the following response to be sent:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 28 Apr 2019 17:28:27 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Content-Encoding: br
Server: gws
Content-Length: 55786
... etc
```

Now, after reading all response headers using `streamReader.ReadLine()` and parsing the content length found in the response header, let's read the response content into a buffer:

```
var totalBytesRead = 0;
int bytesRead;
var buffer = new byte[contentLength];
do
{
    bytesRead = sslStream.Read(buffer,
        totalBytesRead,
        contentLength - totalBytesRead);
    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
} while (totalBytesRead < contentLength && bytesRead > 0);
```

However, this `do..while` loop will only exit after the connection has been closed by the remote server, which means the last call to `Read` will hang. Which means we've already read the entire response content, and the server is already listening for another HTTP message on this stream. Is the `contentLength` incorrect? Does the `streamReader` read too much when calling `ReadLine` and therefore does it mess up the `SslStream` position, which causes invalid data to be read?

What gives? Has anyone had experience with this?

P.S. Here is a sample console app code with all safety checks omitted which demonstrates this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient("google.com", 443))
    {
        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        using (var sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false))
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("google.com");
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(sslStream))
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(sslStream))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("GET / HTTP/1.1");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Host: www.google.com");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Accept-Language: sr,sr-RS;q=0.8,sr-CS;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Connection: keep-alive");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
                streamWriter.WriteLine();
                streamWriter.Flush();

                var lines = new List<string>();
                var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                var contentLength = 0;
                while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                {
                    var split = line.Split(": ");
                    if (split.First() == "Content-Length")
                    {
                        contentLength = int.Parse(split[1]);
                    }

                    lines.Add(line);
                    line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                }

                var totalBytesRead = 0;
                int bytesRead;
                var buffer = new byte[contentLength];
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = sslStream.Read(buffer,
                        totalBytesRead,
                        contentLength - totalBytesRead);
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"Bytes read: {totalBytesRead} of {contentLength} (last chunk: {bytesRead} bytes)");
                } while (totalBytesRead < contentLength && bytesRead > 0);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "--------------------");
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**EDIT**

This always happens after I submit a question. I've been scratching my head for a couple of days without being able to find the cause of the problem, but as soon as I submitted it, I knew it was something to do with `StreamReader` messing things up when trying to read a line.

So if I stop using the `StreamReader` and replace calls to `ReadLine` with something that reads byte-by-byte, everything seems to be fine. The replacement code can be written as the following:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ReadHeader(Stream sslStream)
{
    // One-byte buffer for reading bytes from the stream
    var buffer = new byte[1];

    // Initialize a four-character string to keep the last four bytes of the message
    var check = new StringBuilder("....");
    int bytes;
    var responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        // Read the next byte from the stream and write in into the buffer
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
        if (bytes == 0)
        {
            // If nothing was read, break the loop
            break;
        }

        // Add the received byte to the response builder.
        // We expect the header to be ASCII encoded so it's OK to just cast to char and append
        responseBuilder.Append((char) buffer[0]);

        // Always remove the first char from the string and append the latest received one
        check.Remove(0, 1);
        check.Append((char) buffer[0]);

        // \r\n\r\n marks the end of the message header, so break here
        if (check.ToString() == "\r\n\r\n")
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (bytes > 0);

    var headerText = responseBuilder.ToString();
    return headerText.Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

...which would then make our sample console app look like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient("google.com", 443))
    {
        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        using (var sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false))
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("google.com");
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(sslStream))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("GET / HTTP/1.1");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Host: www.google.com");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Accept-Language: sr,sr-RS;q=0.8,sr-CS;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Connection: keep-alive");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
                streamWriter.WriteLine();
                streamWriter.Flush();

                var lines = ReadHeader(sslStream);
                var contentLengthLine = lines.First(x => x.StartsWith("Content-Length"));
                var split = contentLengthLine.Split(": ");
                var contentLength = int.Parse(split[1]);

                var totalBytesRead = 0;
                int bytesRead;
                var buffer = new byte[contentLength];
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = sslStream.Read(buffer,
                        totalBytesRead,
                        contentLength - totalBytesRead);
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"Bytes read: {totalBytesRead} of {contentLength} (last chunk: {bytesRead} bytes)");
                } while (totalBytesRead < contentLength && bytesRead > 0);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "--------------------");
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> ReadHeader(Stream sslStream)
{
    // One-byte buffer for reading bytes from the stream
    var buffer = new byte[1];

    // Initialize a four-character string to keep the last four bytes of the message
    var check = new StringBuilder("....");
    int bytes;
    var responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        // Read the next byte from the stream and write in into the buffer
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
        if (bytes == 0)
        {
            // If nothing was read, break the loop
            break;
        }

        // Add the received byte to the response builder.
        // We expect the header to be ASCII encoded so it's OK to just cast to char and append
        responseBuilder.Append((char)buffer[0]);

        // Always remove the first char from the string and append the latest received one
        check.Remove(0, 1);
        check.Append((char)buffer[0]);

        // \r\n\r\n marks the end of the message header, so break here
        if (check.ToString() == "\r\n\r\n")
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (bytes > 0);

    var headerText = responseBuilder.ToString();
    return headerText.Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Comment: This behavior is due to `Connection: keep-alive` in the request headers. If you want it to close the connection after the response has been read, change it to `Connection: close`. If you need to keep the connection for another request, trust the content length and don't do a blocking read because the server's waiting for you to write another request.

Comment: @madreflection `Connection: keep-alive` can't be the problem because I've received the `Content-Length` header and I try to read the exact number of bytes from the response stream, which should begin right after the last response header followed by an empty line. I don't wanna close the connection after the response has been read, but I want to read the response content properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is **YES**.
It can be trusted, as long as you read the message header properly, i.e. do not use `StreamReader.ReadLine`.

Here is a utility method which does the job:

```
private static string ReadStreamUntil(Stream stream, string boundary)
{
    // One-byte buffer for reading bytes from the stream
    var buffer = new byte[1];

    // Initialize a string builder with some placeholder chars of the length as the boundary
    var boundaryPlaceholder = string.Join(string.Empty, boundary.Select(x => "."));
    var check = new StringBuilder(boundaryPlaceholder);
    var responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        // Read the next byte from the stream and write in into the buffer
        var byteCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
        if (byteCount == 0)
        {
            // If nothing was read, break the loop
            break;
        }

        // Add the received byte to the response builder.
        responseBuilder.Append((char)buffer[0]);

        // Always remove the first char from the string and append the latest received one
        check.Remove(0, 1);
        check.Append((char)buffer[0]);

        // boundary marks the end of the message, so break here
    } while (check.ToString() != boundary);

    return responseBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Then, to read the header, we can just call `ReadStreamUntil(sslStream, "\r\n\r\n")`.

The key here is to read the stream byte by byte until a known byte sequence (in this case \r\n\r\n) is encountered.

After it's been read by using this method, the stream will be at the correct position for the response content to be read properly.

If any good, this method can easily be converted to async variant by calling `await ReadAsync` instead of `Read`.

It's worth noting that the above method only works fine if the text is ASCII encoded.

Comment: Very accurate answer, I dealt with this myself for two days. But I'm surprised you can't use the exact number of bytes to read - the sock library should work that way. 

I'll try to check at the level of `Socket`. First of all - MTU is not one byte...